# Site loading time improvement

Tags: php, performance, web, performance-testing

today I was checking for the loading time of the site. I used net panle in firebug to see which resource takes how much time.

I have attached the spanshot for the result.

In this snalshot I ma bit confused about the last three resources which I have marked.

My question is that why its start loading after very long wait? Those resources taking only few seconds to load but those are starting after a big delay.

Any reason for this?

[image: Site loading time measurement using Net panel of mozilla]

Comment: Are those files loaded by javascript? May be something that fires on an event such as window.load?

Comment: Make sure you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to bypass the browser's internal cache.

Comment: @mark: that also done, do u want to see the screen shot with bypassed cache?

Comment: @Avinash: Looks like font files to me (but not anything I've seen before). What loads them? A markup such as `<link href='cabin-regular-webfont.woff' rel='idk'>` or a script?

Comment: @salman: those are font webkit file. i.e: Webkit files of the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The load time(s) are still minimal... the gap is WHEN they were loaded... i.e. may have been a slight slowdown on DNS or something. Have you loaded multiple times, is it always the same?

Comment: Look at image in full resolution. The query is run a IP, all elements are loaded from the same IP. no DNS timeout on IP access

Comment: The image it's self is not a link to a full resolution image, and I can't seem to find an obvious way to get the full rez version. Do you mind posting the link? @regilero

Comment: @Brian: yes i have loaded multiple time, and its same for those resources.

Answer (score 0):

delete the cache and see if it still happens with and after: 200 OK!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual page its impossible to say why. But most the URLs are triggered by a timer object (have a look at a page here - once you start composing an answer, it will start to fire back requests to save a draft).

Another reason may be that the browser was just to busy running javascript to get round to loading those URLs.

BTW, with all those 304 responses, your sites performance must be pretty awful anyway.

PS, take the gloves off next time you post.

Answer (score 0):

Try the page speed tab. See if there is any javascript block taking some time to execute and thus causing the break in page loading.

Is there any Flash loading?

Any video?

Anything other than html, css, javascript and small images?

Comment: the three things which I have pointed are the webkit fonts files.

Answer (score 0):

Red line on firebug means "load" event (not DOM load event!). So, some of the requests are made after the page loads. Look at your scripts, may be something loads after everything is loaded.